# Custom Annotation Is Not Picking by springboott

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have created Custom Annotation in Spring-boot, But it is not recognizing. My custom annotation want some validation, But spring-boot not picking up that annotation. Here is my code

```
//creating custom annotation
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD})
@Documented

@Constraint(validatedBy = Mobile_EmailValidation.class)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    String message() /*default "Invalid phone number"*/;
    int min();
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
// for validation class

public class  Mobile_EmailValidation implements ConstraintValidator<CustomAnnotation, String> {

    static{
        System.out.println("hi this is static block");
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomAnnotation constraintAnnotation) {
     System.out.println("hi this annotation works");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String contactField,
                           ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("hi this annotation works");
        if (contactField == null)
            return true;

        boolean isValid;
        if (contactField.length()<10) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        else {
            isValid = true;
        }}

//this is my entity class

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseDomain {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 40)
    private String name;


@CustomAnnotation(message = "invalid messages",min=4)

@Column(name = "email_id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
private String emailId;
```

Please help me out this annotation is not executed.Tell me is there any extra configuration is required. Please help me out.

Comment: I tried these thing from last 2days ,I lost my hopes .so pls help me out

Comment: It worked for me. How are you testing your annotation???